# svn "path not found" error when creating a branch using HTTPS

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

I am trying to create a new branch in Subversion repository with a bit non-standard structure: instead of `repo/trunk` there is `org/trunk/repo`.  The access is available only using HTTPS protocol.

I was trying to create a branch in **semi-standard way** *(note: the command below is redacted a bit)*

```
$ svn copy \
  https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/trunk/repo \
  https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/branches/foo/repo \
  -m "Create a 'foo' branch of /trunk/repo"
```

This command resulted in strange 'path not found' error:

```
svn: '/svnroot/ph/org/!svn/bc/71/branches/foo' path not found
```

I don't think it is permission problem, as the following command

```
$ svn copy \
  https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/trunk/repo \
  https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/branches/foo_repo \
  -m "Create a 'foo' branch of /trunk/repo"
```

succeeded

```
Committed revision 72.
```

What might be the cause of this problem?  How can I work around it?

---

Subversion server is at version 1.6.19 (r1383947), subversion client is 1.6.17 (r1128011).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default you can not create intermediate directories on the fly. There is the **--parents** switch to do this. So the correct command should be:

```
svn copy --parents \
https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/trunk/repo \
https://svn.example.org/svnroot/ph/org/branches/foo/repo \
-m "Create a 'foo' branch of /trunk/repo"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you first create the repository, you ran "svn mkdir branches" to create the branch folder.  It stands to reason that you need to run a mkdir command to make foo before you can create a branch to that (currently) non-existant folder.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Make the target directories in working copy, 'add' them, commit, then do the svn copy. Worked for me.